# How to find the number of values in a given range that has a certain remainder when divided by a given number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Given four integers `N, L, R and Rem`. I have to find the the number of values between `L and R`(inclusive) that gives remainder `Rem` when divided by `N`.

For example: If `N = 3, L = 2, R = 10 and Rem = 1` then the numbers with remainder 1 when divided by 3 in this range are `{4, 7, 10}`. So, the answer is 3.

Here is the brute force approach I coded:

```
int main() {
    int N, L, R, Rem;
    cin >> N >> L >> R >> Rem;

    int Ans = 0;
    for (int i = L; i <= R; i++) {
        if (i % N == Rem)
            Ans++;
    }
    cout << Ans << endl;
}
```

What would be a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: If you have two numbers, `A` and `B` and you divide them by `N` and they have the same remainder then `A + NC = B` for some integer `C`

Comment: You have to reduce loop, instead i++ use i += N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the number of such values in the range `[0, n)`:

```
template<class T>
T count(T n, T div, T rem) {
    assert(rem < div);
    return (n + div - rem - 1) / div;
}
```

Then subtract, `[0, max + 1) \ [0, min) = [min, max]`:

```
template<class T>
T count(T min, T max, T div, T rem) {
    assert(min >= 0);
    assert(min <= max);
    return count(max + 1, div, rem) - count(min, div, rem);
}
```

---

> Obviously, it doesn't work for negative values. The OP specified input as integers, not positive integers.

This answer assumes that all the integers are non-negative numbers. The reason is simple: we all agree on what the remainder is for non-negative numbers, but [different definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) exist for negative ones. The problem wording says nothing about which definition should be taken. For example, in C++ itself before C++11, the standard specified the result of `a % b` to be *implementation-defined* if either `a < 0` or `b < 0`. The reason is the following difference in how `/` operator is defined for integral operands:

- Until C++11:

  > The quotient is rounded in implementation-defined direction.
- Since C++11:

  > The quotient is truncated towards zero (fractional part is discarded).

Hence, `%` and `std::div` might give different results – before C++11, the latter function followed the "fractional part is discarded" rule.

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't work for negative values. The OP specified input as integers, not positive integers.

Comment: @ciamej, added a few words about negatives.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR** it is *roughly* (R-L+1)/N give or take +- 1

for instance
L=2
R=10
N=3
REM=0

the numbers are 3,6,9
(R-L+1)/N = (10-2+1)/3 = 9/3 = 3

here's an **accurate** solution with explanation, that requires no loops

find the first number greater or equals to L that divides nicely by N

`L = (L % N == rem)? L :  L +     (REM - L%N + N)%N`

find the last number smaller or equals to R that divides nicely by N

`R = (R % N == rem)? R : R - (N - (REM - R%N + N)%N)`

the result is

`int result = ((R-L)/N) + 1`

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't work for negative values. The OP specified input as integers, not positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
(R - L) / N 
+ 1 if (R - L) % N ≥ (rem - L) % N
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The answer is **floor((R-Rem)/N)-ceil((L-Rem)/N)+1**
where ceil(a/b)=(a+b-1)/b
floor(a/b) = a/b
Assuming a and b are positive here. It does not work for negative numbers though.

Proof:
Another way to think in terms of inequalities,

L<=N * K<=R

L<=N * K+1<=R

.
.
.

L<=N * K+N-1<=R

Note: Here K is the quotient (It is a pretty standard division rule learned in school)

To solve your case, consider the inequality

L<=N * K+Rem<=R

ceil((L-Rem)/N)<=K<=floor((R-Rem)/N)

so the answer is **floor((R-Rem)/N)-ceil((L-Rem)/N)+1**
where ceil(a/b)=(a+b-1)/b
floor(a/b) = a/b
Assuming a and b are positive here. It does not work for negative numbers though.